# cscope cannot use in vim

Tags: c, linux, vim, cscope

I cannot use cscope in vim. The commands below are not work

```
:cs find s {name}
:cs find c {name}
...
```

The error code is about "E259 No matches found..." but I add and execute the database exactly.

I use `:cs show` to show the database I use, and there is nothing wrong.

Here are the command I build:

```
find "$(pwd -P)" -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" > cscope.files
cscope -Rbqk -i cscope.files
```

and I set the `:cs add /path/to/database/cscope.out` in `.vimrc`

By build and add database with absolute paths, I think I can get the database in every `c` files in any subfolders.

The weird thing is, I can use cscope and find the symbol by:

```
cscope -Rqk -i cscope.files
```

I think something wrong about my vim but I don't know how to figure out.

Please, I need some helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should consult cscope-intro help tag:

```
:help cscope-intro
```

(in the vim screen)

to get the full help to the interace of `vim` to `cscope`.  It requires to build the database to use from your source files first, so probably the used database is empty and that's the reason you don't find anything.

`Vim`'s `cscope` commands are an interface (as it is told in the help page I recommended you to use) to the `cscope` shell command, so the most probable cause that it doesn't work is that you have not established a database to consult when using it.